# MS Word, can we write a multilingual regular expression?

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, macros

I want to find all the occurrences of the from x.y and change it to x,y where x and y are numbers:
I was using this: `([0-9]).([0-9)` and doing the replace using `\1,\2`

but here is the catch , if the point is an Arabic character, once it is replaced with the comma which is an English character it causes the numbers to switch:

example : `x.y` is becoming `y,x`

so can I include **multiple** languages information in the regular expression ?
something like `([0-9])(.A)([0-9])`

I was trying to write a macro for it but I am also stuck at detecting the language(more precisely the direction ) of the point, for more info see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32095169/ms-word-find-and-replace-change-how-to-replace-based-on-captured-values-in-find)

**EDIT**
Examples:
 1) the point is English:  2.5   becomes 2,5
 2) the point is Arabic: 2.5 becomes 5,2 but it should become 2,5

Comment: Have you tried using UTF escapes like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/150078/5103963)? You could replace the `.` with `[A-Za-z]` to find and replace English. Then use a similar pattern to find and replace Arabic and then other languages.

Comment: Both arabic and English dots has the same code point, 002E. So I don't this trick would be helpful

Comment: Any idea how does MS WORD distinguish between the two?

Comment: Oh, my bad. I thought the `.` was referring to the regex wild card, but you are trying to match a literal dot. If they have the same Unicode escape, are you sure that MS distinguishes them?

Comment: Yes I am sure, but I don't know how it is keeping track of that.

Comment: Could you give 'before and after' examples of when MS Word functions correctly and incorrectly?

Comment: @NonlinearFruit, is it clear enough ?

Comment: Yes, thanks! Is Arabic the default language in MS Word?

Comment: what do you mean exactly by Default language ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27435/discussion-between-nonlinearfruit-and-mhd-tahawi).